# Ruby on Rails pass value to another view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Mailboxer as my messaging gem in my rails app.

So the site's about classifieds. Every classified has a contact seller link , which i have implemented to route to the new_message form and write the message to the recipient fine!

Now i want to add some info about the classified that the contact form is made for!

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:recipient_id])
  end


  def name 
    first_name
  end



  def mailboxer_email(object)
    email
  end



  def create
    recipients = User.find_by(id: params[:recipient_id])
    conversation = current_user.send_message(recipients, params[:message][:body], params[:message][:subject]).conversation
    flash[:success] = "Message has been sent!"
    redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
  end



end
```

This is the view where i call new_message_path and then retrieve the user_id to define the recipient.

```
<div class="center-div">
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="image">
        <%  @classified.photos.each do |p| %>


        <h3 class="dark-grey"><%= @classified.title %></h3>
        <h5 class="dark-grey">Loved by: <%= @classified.favorited_by.count %> </h5>

        <%= image_tag p.image %>

        <%end%>

    </div>


    <%= link_to "", new_message_path(:recipient_id => @classified.user_id), :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" , :style => "color:#EFCE7B" %>

    <%if current_user.favorite_classifieds.collect(&:classified_id).include?(@classified.id) %>
    <%= link_to "", favorite_classified_path(@classified, type: "unfavorite") , :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-heart" , :style => "color:#FF0000", method: :put %>

    <%else%>

    <%= link_to "", favorite_classified_path(@classified, type: "favorite") , :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-heart" , :style => "color:#000000", method: :put %>
    <%end%>


    <%= link_to "", editlisting_path(@classified) , :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-flag"  , :style => "color:#EB573B" %>
    <ul> 


        <h3 class="dark-grey">Model</h3>
        <li><%= @classified.model %></li>
        <h3 class="dark-grey">Description</h3>
        <li><%= @classified.description %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Back", '/' , :class => "link" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to @classified.user.first_name, profile_path(@classified.user_id) %></li>


    </ul>
</div>
```

and this is my message_new view where i want to have the data of the classified

```
<div class="center-div">
  <div class="messages-box">
    <% page_header "Αποστολή μηνύματος" %>

    <%= form_tag messages_path, method: :post do %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= label_tag 'message[subject]', 'Subject' %>

        <%= text_field_tag 'message[subject]', nil, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <%= label_tag 'message[body]', 'Message' %>
        <%= text_area_tag 'message[body]', nil, cols: 3, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">

      <%= hidden_field_tag(:recipient_id, "#{@user.id}") %>
      </div>

      <%= submit_tag 'Send', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

also for any solution a good explanation would help me a lot.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using nested routes.

```
resources :classifieds do
      put :favorite, on: :member
      resources :messages do
      end
    end
```

this is my view

```
<div class="center-div">
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="image">
        <%  @classified.photos.each do |p| %>


        <h3 class="dark-grey"><%= @classified.title %></h3>
        <h5 class="dark-grey">Loved by: <%= @classified.favorited_by.count %> </h5>

        <%= image_tag p.image %>

        <%end%>

    </div>


    <%= link_to "", new_classified_message_path(:recipient_id => @classified.user_id , :classified_id => @classified.id), :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" , :style => "color:#EFCE7B" %>

    <%if current_user.favorite_classifieds.collect(&:classified_id).include?(@classified.id) %>
    <%= link_to "", favorite_classified_path(@classified, type: "unfavorite") , :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-heart" , :style => "color:#FF0000", method: :put %>

    <%else%>

    <%= link_to "", favorite_classified_path(@classified, type: "favorite") , :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-heart" , :style => "color:#000000", method: :put %>
    <%end%>


    <%= link_to "", editlisting_path(@classified) , :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-flag"  , :style => "color:#EB573B" %>
    <ul> 


        <h3 class="dark-grey">Model</h3>
        <li><%= @classified.model %></li>
        <h3 class="dark-grey">Description</h3>
        <li><%= @classified.description %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Back", '/' , :class => "link" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to @classified.user.first_name, profile_path(@classified.user_id) %></li>


    </ul>
</div>
```

Got the value from the controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:recipient_id])
    @classified = Classified.find_by(id: params[:classified_id])
  end


  def name 
    first_name
  end



  def mailboxer_email(object)
    email
  end



  def create
    classifieds = Classified.find_by(id: params[:classified_id])
    recipients = User.find_by(id: params[:recipient_id])
    conversation = current_user.send_message(recipients, params[:message][:body], params[:message][:subject]).conversation
    flash[:success] = "Message has been sent!"
    redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
  end



end
```

and last rendered it in my messages_new view

```
<div class="center-div">
  <div class="messages-box">
    <% page_header "Αποστολή μηνύματος" %>

    <%= form_tag messages_path, method: :post do %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= label_tag 'message[subject]', 'Αποστολή μηνύματος για την αγγελία : ' %>
        <%= label_tag(:classified_id, "#{@classified.title}") %>    <!-- integrate this -->

        <%= text_field_tag 'message[subject]', nil, class: 'form-control', required: true %> <!-- integrate here -->
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <%= label_tag 'message[body]', 'Μύνημα στον χρήστη : ' %>
        <%= label_tag(:recipient_id, "#{@user.first_name}") %>


        <%= text_area_tag 'message[body]', nil,rows: 15, cols: 3, class: 'form-control', required: true %> <!-- integrate here -->
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <%= hidden_field_tag(:recipient_id, "#{@user.id}") %>
      </div>

      <%= submit_tag 'Send', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```